# Computer verification for hyperbolic trigonometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, computer-algebra, symbolic-computation

I am currently writing a paper that requires some lengthy computations using basic hyperbolic trigonometry. So, several hyperbolic figures appear, and we apply the law of sines and so on in order to relate angles and sides to each other. The problem is that this is quite trivial and very much unrelated to the mathematical content of the paper.

My guess is that a classical solution would be to put all these computations in an appendix at the end. Then, I fear that a journal editor may see these computations as a waste of precious journal pages (I am sort of ashamed about this because I guess I should not care if it doesn't get published for this reason, but I still have to find a permanent job and the bills aren't going to start paying themselves). I suppose I could just state the final formulas in the journal version and cite a longer arXiv version with the computations, but I am not sure if this is standard journal practice.

Finally, I realized that maybe I could use some software to "verify" my computations, so that I could use the formulas in the paper and cite the computer verification (I have seen that you can upload computer code and the sort when you submit);  I guess it's also an opportunity to learn how to use a new tool.

Unfortunately, I do not know of such software and a google search has not yielded anything. Does such a program exist? By this I mean that I should be able to introduce the figures symbolically (specifying the points, which angles are right, and so on), and then apply trigonometric laws and the properties of hyperbolic functions to compute symbolically the relevant formulas.

Comment: May be there is no software for your special problem. But why not Mathematica, Sage, Maple?